# Quiero mostrar imágenes aleatorias de un array cada X segundos con angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

Estoy intentando mostrar un array de imágenes, pero me da error de que no reconoce la propiedad length. Os adjunto mi código

archivo TS

```
export class ImagesComponent implements OnInit {
  public images=[
    {src:'assets/img/28.png'},
    {src:'assets/img/53.png'},
    {src:'assets/img/43.png'}
  ];
  constructor(
    private _wordService: WordService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     setInterval(() => {
       this.images = this.getRandomImages();
     }, 5000);
  }

  getRandomImages() {
   const randomNum: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.images.length - 1)) + 0;
   return this.images[randomNum];
  }



}
```

archivo HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let image of images">
      <img [src]="image.src" alt="">
   </div>
```

Código de error en el navegador:

```
ImagesComponent.html:16 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.js:5642)
    at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:3157)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9246)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10507)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10469)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11102)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11062)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ImagesComponent.html:16)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11054)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10451)
View_ImagesComponent_0 @ ImagesComponent.html:16
proxyClass @ compiler.js:10173
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:11306
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1719
(anonymous) @ core.js:4578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:3779
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:4578
(anonymous) @ core.js:4462
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:3820
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run @ core.js:3734
next @ core.js:4462
schedulerFn @ core.js:3551
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:195
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:133
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:3535
checkStable @ core.js:3789
onLeave @ core.js:3856
onInvokeTask @ core.js:3814
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:485
timer @ zone.js:2054
setInterval (async)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2075
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:255
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:1114
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2090
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1394
push../src/app/components/images/images.component.ts.ImagesComponent.ngOnInit @ images.component.ts:26
checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline @ core.js:9243
checkAndUpdateNodeInline @ core.js:10507
checkAndUpdateNode @ core.js:10469
debugCheckAndUpdateNode @ core.js:11102
debugCheckDirectivesFn @ core.js:11062
(anonymous) @ ImagesComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1
debugUpdateDirectives @ core.js:11054
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:10451
callViewAction @ core.js:10692
execEmbeddedViewsAction @ core.js:10655
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:10452
callViewAction @ core.js:10692
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:10634
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:10457
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:11344
debugCheckAndUpdateView @ core.js:11022
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges @ core.js:8838
(anonymous) @ core.js:4571
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:4571
(anonymous) @ core.js:4462
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:3820
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run @ core.js:3734
next @ core.js:4462
schedulerFn @ core.js:3551
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:195
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:133
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:3535
checkStable @ core.js:3789
onHasTask @ core.js:3833
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ zone.js:441
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:461
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:285
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:205
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:962
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:4345
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
```

Muchas gracias y un saludo

Comment: Sí, te lo pongo debajo del código

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres hacer exactamente, pero lo que pasa es que `this.images` lo estás sobreescribiendo con una de las imágenes en tu `setInterval`

Comment: Quiero que cada 5 segundos, se me muestre una imagen del array json que he creado

Comment: entonces estas usando el ngFor sin sentido si quieres mostrar una imagen aleatoria, simplemente elimina el ngFor.

El error ``Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed`` es debido a que estas intentando usar ngFor en un objeto

Comment: aún así, si lo elimino me sigue fallando. Es decir, me muestra por pantalla los 3 arrays ( [Objetc Object] y a los 5 segundos desaparece y ya no continua mostrando. Y si quito la etiqueta img y pongo solo {{image.src}} también me falla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver si esto te lo soluciona, porque me parece que te has liado mezclando ideas:

```
export class ImagesComponent implements OnInit {
  private images=[
    {src:'assets/img/28.png'},
    {src:'assets/img/53.png'},
    {src:'assets/img/43.png'}
  ];
  private currentImage: any;

  constructor(private _wordService: WordService) {
    //inicializamos con la primera imagen
    this.currentImage = this.updateRandomImage();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     setInterval(() => {
       //cada 5 segundos elegimos una imagen al azar
       this.currentImage = this.updateRandomImage();
     }, 5000);
  }

  updateRandomImage() {
    const r= Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.images.length - 1)) + 0;
    return this.images[r];
  }

  getImage() {
    return this.currentImage.src;
  }

}
```

Y en tu template simplemente mostramos la elegida en cada momento, que debería actualizarse cada 5 segundos:

```
<img [src]="getImage()" alt="">
```

Comment: Si busca aletoriedad, seria bueno llamar ``updateRandomImage() `` en el onInit antes del interval, de esta manera obtendra la primera imagen de manera aleatoria tambien

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, actualizado

Comment: Muchísimas gracias chicos, me ha servido